# AngularJS filter syntax

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'd like to supply a filter value via a variable.  What is wrong with the ng-repeat line below where I attempted to include the model reference {{fil}}?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : {{fil}}">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

<p>This example displays only the names containing the letter {{ fil }}.</p>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
    $scope.fil = "a";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it without interpolation`{{}}`, so it will apply filter `fil` which is there in scope.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : fil">
    {{ x }}
</li>
```